# Нужны ли кавычки при ссылке на рисунок?

Tags: пунктуация, оформление-текста

Пишу текст, в котором есть рисунок с подписью (Рис. 1. Название рисунка).
Стоит ли при упоминании его в статье (например, см. рис. 1) заключать фразу "рис. 1" в кавычки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все виды изображений именуются рисунками. (Иллюстративный материал может быть представлен не только рисунками, но и фотографиями, графиками, схемами, диаграммами...) Подпись даётся под рисунком, в конце подписи – точка (затем могут идти примечания, пояснения):

**??????  ++++++++ ((((  )))))**
Рис. 1. Название рисунка [в конце ставится точка].

Сокращение **рис.** пишется с пробелом после точки: **рис. 1, рис. 3.2.**
 Например:
***На рис. 2 представлены данные; ...в соответствии с графиком (см. рис. 3.7).***

Сокращения не стоит употреблять без крайней необходимости, желательно все слова писать полностью; переносы не используются; кавычки не ставятся.

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ полностью понятен.